# EGit freezes when adding from unstaged changes to staged changes in Staging view

Tags: egit

For a reasonably sized project, when dragging files from the "Unstaged Changes" pane to the "Staged Changes" pane in the "Git Staging" view in EGit, the entire workspace freezes for about 15-20 seconds even for a single file. The same via command line almost finishes instantaneously. Is this tracked in a known EGit issue and more importantly are there are workarounds?

Thanks in advance!

Configuration:

- eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64 (with patch from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/junoSR1Patch-tmp)
- RHEL (6.3) 2.6.32
- 8-CPU 64bit
- 8 GB RAM
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a change to improve performance for this, which is to be released with EGit 2.2 on 2012-12-19:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/2.2#Re-indexing_repositories_is_now_done_incrementally

If you don't want to wait until then, update to the nightly build from the [nightly update site](http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly).

Comment: Thanks - looking forward to the release version then!

Comment: The problem no longer exists in the new version. Cheers to the EGit team!